# Removing Windows entry from GRUB menu

Tags: fedora, grub

I have installed Fedora 20 on an external hard drive partition. Windows is installed on an internal hard drive partition. When I boot from USB storage device (that is the external hard drive), GRUB shows both Fedora and Windows. How do I permanently remove the Windows entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may modify yourself the files in /etc/grub.d or /etc/default/grub, but next time you update your system, the Windows entry will be found again, and you will be presented with that option once more.

A more permanent solution would be to make the file /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober non-executable, so that Windows will not be found. This has the drawback that, if you install other OSes on your external hard drive, they won't be found either. But so long as you only wish to boot a single OS from the HDD, you are fine, and can update grub as much as you like without Windows re-appearing.

If instead you wish to boot multiple OSes on the HDD, then the above solution fails, but you may use the following hack. Edit (as sudo) /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober, and locate the following line:

```
  OSPROBED="`os-prober  | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
```

modify it as follows:

```
  OSPROBED="`os-prober | grep /dev/sdb | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
```

if your HDD is sdb, otherwise change it accordingly. Then search for

```
 LINUXPROBED="`linux-boot-prober ${DEVICE} 2> /dev/null |  tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
```

and modify it to

```
 LINUXPROBED="`linux-boot-prober ${DEVICE} 2> /dev/null |grep /dev/sdb|  tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`"
```

These are old tricks, cannot claim they are mine.

Comment: Might be better to simply filter out Windows: `os-prober | grep -vi windows | tr ' ' '^' | paste -s -d ' '`

Comment: @terdon good point.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `grub.cfg` in `/boot/grub/`. Open it with your favorite editor and remove (better yet: comment out) the whole section from `### BEGIN ...` to `### END ...` that contains something like `menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/..."`